# Understanding Rcpp plugins

Tags: c++, r, dependencies, rcpp

I'm looking over the demo provided in [3.6 of the Rcpp-FAQ](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf), and I'm trying to understanding how this plugin is being created. The standalone example provided is

```
gslrng <-
'int seed = Rcpp::as<int>(par) ;
gsl_rng_env_setup();
gsl_rng *r = gsl_rng_alloc (gsl_rng_default);
gsl_rng_set (r, (unsigned long) seed);
double v = gsl_rng_get (r);
gsl_rng_free(r);return Rcpp::wrap(v);'

plug <- Rcpp:::Rcpp.plugin.maker(
  include.before = "#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>",
  libs = paste("-L/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/lib -lRcpp",
               "-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/lib",
               "-L/usr/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm"))
registerPlugin("gslDemo", plug )
fun <- cxxfunction(signature(par="numeric"), gslrng, plugin="gslDemo")
fun(0)
```

Specifically, why is that call to `paste()` being comma-separated like that? Should **all** dependencies (header file directories, linker directories, and name of library files) be handled via plugins?

Comment: Is this a followup question to [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54168141/8416610)? In that case it might make sense if you tell us what you are trying to achieve. The question about `paste` is basic R, while the second question is quite vague.

Comment: @RalfStubner It is indeed! (thank you for your help). My ultimate goal is to help c++-averse statisticians use a [c++ library I wrote](https://github.com/tbrown122387/pf). I get paste, it was the [commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562403/i-dont-understand-wl-rpath-wl) that was throwing me.

Comment: Ok. Now I understand which commas you mean. I have not looked closely at your library, but would it be necessary for the user to write C++ code or can all the functionality of the library exposed as R functions? In the latter case you would not need a Rcpp plugin. Just include the library in the R package and use Rcpp to interface between R and the library.

Comment: @RalfStubner unfortunately they would need to write a c++ header for every model/filter pair (something like [this](https://github.com/tbrown122387/pf/blob/master/examples/svol_bs.h)  Compilation needs to be re-done every time you change the model or inherit from a different filter.

Comment: Can you make the library header-only like RcppEigen or RcppAramdillo? That would simplify things a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `paste()` is a vanilla use of base R's `paste()` -- it creates a *single* string containing *all* the link instructions being passed to `libs`.

For `include.before` we do not need that as only one header is passed.

I would recommend you study the code *along with its use* as well as the *actual plugin for RcppGSL* which is defined [here](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppgsl/blob/b444404a0fa564bcb8b9472ea7aab7c493b346dc/R/inline.R#L47-59) and see how they are used in packages such as *e.g.* `RcppZiggurat`.  And by used I mean see what the instructions expand to when the client packages compiles and links.

It looks crazy complicated but hey it has worked for about a decade already :)